# Will VNC use an Onboard Graphics or the external Graphics Card when connected to it?

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card

I have a computer with a onboard graphics card which I use for a server.  It doesn't have a monitor so I connect to it via VNC.  My question is, if I install a graphics card, will the computer use the interface graphics card even without a monitor connected to it? Or will it continue to use the onboard graphics?

Comment: why would you install a card, you do not use graphics as you say you only do vnc etc. Graphic card might increase the temperature of your system, even if no monitor is plugged. worth thinking of...

Comment: @MrSimpleMind The "why" doesn't matter. Maybe he does have something in the machine that would benefit from a graphic card, i.e.: a physics simulating program that could benefit from Physix.

Comment: The server is using using extensive graphics. That's why I'm wondering if installing a card would help it.

Comment: What OS do you use ?

Comment: I'm using windows 8

Answer (score 3):

option 1.
look in the bios, if there is any option to disable the onboard graphic card.

option 2.
in windows 8, graphic tool (e.g. nvidia control panel etc) normally there is option for 3d etc, you can give the preferred graphic card (depends on vendor tools etc).

this may defer from hardware to hardware, vendor tools, bios, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :

> Elderly graphics cards or drivers may make quite a difference; this is a graphics-intensive application! On Windows the graphics system on the server will affect the speed as well as the one on the viewer.

Source: [VNC faq](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/vnc_docs/faq.html).

Comment: I see. So adding a graphics card will affect the performance in a good way right?

Comment: As long as its chipset is better than the onboard one, yes. How much better performance will be, though, can only be found out experimentally. There is a good chance that the benefits won't be worth the investment.